# Hibernate JPA peristence configuration in Jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss7.x

I moved to Hibernate Persistence instead of OpenJPA persistence  and I changed my persistence.xml as below

```
      <persistence-unit name="pac">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <jta-data-source>pac</jta-data-source>
    <class>xxxx</class>
    <class>xxxx</class>
    <class>xxxxx</class>
    <class>xxxxxr</class>
    <class>xxxxx</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
       </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="User">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>tUser</jta-data-source>
        <class>xxxxr</class>
      <class>xxxxx</class>
      <class>xxxxx</class>
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
       <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:1521:pac811"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ConnectionUserName" value="xyz"/>
    <property name="hibernate.ConnectionPassword" value="abc"/>      
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
      value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />

  </properties>
```

I added org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence and c3p0 property,oracle dialect extra in the existing persistence xml also changed the code and it is compiling fine.
Now I am worrying about what are the configuration steps required when deployed in JBOSS for this HibernatePersistence,oracle dialect and c3p0 connection.
current Jboss server is Jboss redhat 6.4
I am using hibernate 4.2.1. Any body help on this it would be helpful if provide the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You are in JBoss and must use the DataSource that is configured in JBoss.

Remove all these lines

```
 <property name="hibernate.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:1521:pac811"/>
<property name="hibernate.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="hibernate.ConnectionUserName" value="xyz"/>
<property name="hibernate.ConnectionPassword" value="abc"/>      
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
  value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

**Is tUser the DataSource you configured in standalone.xml?**

Comment: Yes it is configured in JBOSS

Comment: sorry it is not configured in standalone.xml

Comment: you have to configure a datasource in standalone.xml becaus JBoss will managed the connectoin pool. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 It's not recommended to do the connection management yourself